# Как одновременно запустить несколько бесконечных циклов в Python?

Tags: python, многопоточность, циклы

Нужно одновременно выполнить несколько бесконечных циклов, но программа выполняет только первый поток с первым `while True`.

```
import time
from threading import Thread

class Thread1(Thread):
    while True:
        time.sleep(2)
        for i in range(1):
            print("Hello")

class Thread2(Thread):
    while True:
        time.sleep(4)
        for i in range(1):
            print("Привет")

class Thread3(Thread):
    while True:
        time.sleep(6)
        for i in range(1):
            print("Здравствуйте")

t1 = Thread1()
t1.start()
t2 = Thread2()
t2.start()
t3 = Thread3()
t3.start()
```

Comment: Вы запускаете цикл сразу в момент создания класса Thread1, и до выполнения всех остальных строк кода дело вообще не доходит. Потоки тут вообще ни при чём, потому что до запуска потоков дело вообще не доходит, потому что питон пытается ждать, когда ваш код закончит создавать класс Thread1, а он никогда не закончит, потому что он вечный

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=threading+%5Bpython%5D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не надо писать свои классы, наследующие от `threading.Thread`. Ваш код должен выглядеть так:

```py
import time
from threading import Thread


# Пишем функции для каждого потока
def thread1_func():
    while True:
        time.sleep(2)
        for i in range(1):
            print("Hello")


def thread2_func():
    while True:
        time.sleep(4)
        for i in range(1):
            print("Привет")


def thread3_func():
    while True:
        time.sleep(6)
        for i in range(1):
            print("Здравствуйте")



t1 = Thread(target=thread1_func)  # В именованный аргумент `target` передаём функцию,
t1.start()                        # которая будет выполнятся в этом потоке.
t2 = Thread(target=thread2_func)
t2.start()
t3 = Thread(target=thread3_func)
t3.start()
```